# android layout-normal-xxhdpi rendering for s7 and s10e

Tags: android, android-layout

I use s7 phone to test my android app on real device. On emulator, I use Nexus S, Nexus 7, Nexus 10 to test my app. Today, I bought S10e and tested my app on it. Even though the s10e renders layout file from layout-normal-xxhdpi folder like my s7, the whole xml screen is rendered much smaller than it appears on s7, which confuses me. What I should do to correct the rendering for my s10e?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using *Linear Layouts* use **layout weight** for fill the empty space in layouts.
2. If you are using *Constraint Layouts* use **Guidelines** in layout xml.

Comment: I am using nested layouts. For example: Relative layout inside LinearLayout. And I am using DPs.

Comment: It is pretty clear that I have increase DPs for Samsung Galaxy S10. But the issue is that Galaxy S7 and S10e are both rendered from layout-normal--xxhdpi.

Comment: Big lesson. Avoid using DPs. It is not auto adjusted. The mistake cost to my app 60000 users loss.